# Passing wrong model to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial

First post here, so i'm sorry if this post is not very good!
I am currently building a web application using asp.net, and ran in to this problem:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Daily_Planner.Models.DayPlanPartialview', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Daily_Planner.Models.Group'

It seems like I am having a problem with passing on the right model. I am using several partial views and I am afraid that I may be using my models wrong, however I can not find out what it is. I have tried giving some adequate information, however if you need more I will be more than willing to post more of the code.

Partial view _GroupManage:

```
@model IEnumerable<Daily_Planner.Models.Group>
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.GroupName</option>

    }
</select>
```

Partial view _layout:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Daily Planner", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Daily Planner", "Login", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
}
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    { Html.RenderPartial("_GroupManage"); }
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Daily_Planner.Models
{
    public class DayPlanPartialview 
    { 
     public DayPlan displayComments { get; set; }
     public Group groupM { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Daily_Planner.Models.DayPlan> ListofComments { get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<Daily_Planner.Models.Group> groupmanage{ get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController

```
namespace Daily_Planner.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            private DayPlanPartialview pv = new DayPlanPartialview();


            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                // Add list of comments with newest comment first // .Take(10).ToList(); will only show the last 10 posts
                pv.ListofComments = db.DayPlans.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).ToList();
                return View(pv);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index(DayPlanPartialview dayP)
            {
                dayP.displayComments.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                dayP.displayComments.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                db.DayPlans.Add(dayP.displayComments);
                db.SaveChanges();
                pv.ListofComments = db.DayPlans.ToList();

                return RedirectToAction("");
            } 

     @model IEnumerable<Daily_Planner.Models.Group>
        <select>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.GroupName</option>

            }
        </select>
```

Comment: You need to change `{ Html.RenderPartial("_GroupManage"); }` to `{ Html.RenderPartial("_GroupManage", Model.groupmanage); }`

Comment: Although in your GET method you don;t appear to populate that collection so not sure what your expecting to display. At the very least you will need `pv.groupmanage = new List<Daily_Planner.Models.Group>();` in order for the error to go away.